# Sharepoint images not showing on Android

Tags: android, sharepoint, webview

We are building an Android app that is basicly a webview showing a SPA. The SPA authenticates to the Sharepoint tenant to fetch content from the Sharepoint tenant. This works perfectly in a web browser and in an iOS webview, but on Android the Sharepoint images are not showing. I have tried with these settings, but no luck.

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I just added this line of code:

```js
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance()setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(this.myWebView, true);
```